# ORA-01747 error, update database with inputs

Tags: php, oracle

I'm trying to update my database with inputs but it returns me:

> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification.

I'm not a professional with SQL but I don't see any error on my script. I checked, the column name are exactly the same as my database.

Anyone as an idea?

```
public function updateDepotMethodQuanti($params) {
    
    $sQuery = 'UPDATE depot 
        SET  
            depot.METHOD_SUPV = :0,
            depot.CODE_ETAB_RGLT = :3,
            depot.DATE_RGLT = :4,
            depot.MONTANT_RGLT = :5,
            depot.NUMERO_RGLT = :6,
            depot.COMMENTAIRE = :7,
            depot.BT_COMM_FACTU = :2,
        WHERE depot.ID_DEPOT = :1';
    
    // mise à jour method_supv
    $mResult1 = $this->executeQueries($sQuery,array($params['newMethodQuanti'], $params['idDepot'], $params['checkCommentaire'], $params['codeEtabliReglement'],
            $params['dateReglement'], $params['montant'], $params['numReglement'], $params['motifChangement']
            ));
    
    if ($mResult1 !== false) {
        $this->commit();
    } else {
        $this->rollback();
    }
}
```

The function executeQueries is a function which allows me to use keys like `depot.METHOD_SUPV = :0,`

My logs:

```
2019-03-08T11:35:25+01:00 ERR (3): Exception : array (
'code' => 1747,
'message' => 'ORA-01747: sp�cification utilisateur.table.colonne,table.colonne ou colonne non valide',
'offset' => 337,
'sqltext' => 'UPDATE depot 
        SET  
            depot.METHOD_SUPV = :0,
            depot.CODE_ETAB_RGLT = :3,
            depot.DATE_RGLT = :4,
            depot.MONTANT_RGLT = :5,
            depot.NUMERO_RGLT = :6,
            depot.COMMENTAIRE = :7,
            depot.BT_COMM_FACTU = :2,
        WHERE depot.ID_DEPOT = :1',
 )
 2019-03-08T11:35:25+01:00 ERR (3): Error parameter : array (
  0 => '2',
  1 => '22781811',
  2 => '1',
  3 => '542252',
  4 => '2019-02-25',
  5 => '42542',
  6 => '2452',
  7 => 's<fsdfsdf',
)
```

Comment: Check the names of your columns. Use command : DESC DEPOT;

Comment: It's very hard to debug embedded SQL so  always test your SQL directly, using a database tool like SQL Developer first. Once you know you have a valid SQL statement you can convert it into PHP.

Comment: Also, `[oracle]` and `[mysql]` are two different RDBMS products, albeit owned by the same corporation. Please tag your questions with the correct product, so you get the help you need and people don't waste their time writing responses which you can't use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove comma, here:

```
        depot.BT_COMM_FACTU = :2,     --> here
    WHERE depot.ID_DEPOT = :1
```

Comment: I remove the comma and i got a new error, `ORA-01861: literal does not match format string `

Comment: It means that "date" value you used doesn't match date format. I suggest you use TO_DATE function with appropriate format mask, e.g. `TO_DATE(:4, 'yyyy-mm-dd')` (or whichever format you provide).